# IQueryable with AlphaNumeric sorting

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get this sorting algorithm to work with `IQueryable.OrderBy()`:

https://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting

I have the `AlphanumComparatorFast` class implemented and my code looks like so:

```
           return this.DbContext.IssuesAccessView.AsQueryable()
            .Include(r => r.Issue)
            .Include(r => r.Issue.IssueAttachments)
            .Include(r => r.Issue.IssueParticipants)
            .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
            .Select(y => y.Issue)
            .OrderBy(p => p.IssueNumber, new AlphanumComparatorFast());
```

It compiles fine but Linq has no idea to do with it at runtime because it cannot translate `AlphanumComparatorFast` into SQL, so I get this error

> "this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

The key here is that I do not want to lose the `IQueryable` interface. I need to return queryable for delayed execution.

So my question is, can anyone think of a way to do this? Do I need to use a SQL function(or some such) or can this be done using `IQueryable`?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to CodeNotFound for answering that I do need to create a SQL function to do this.

I have created a function and am trying to call it from C# EF6 Code First(no edmx files) the problem is that I can't find a good example of how to do this. The closest I have gotten is this:

```
[Function(Name = "dbo.fn_CreateAlphanumericSortValue", IsComposable = true)]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")]
public string ReverseCustName([Parameter(Name = "string", DbType = 
"VarChar(100)")] string @string)
{
    return ((string)(this.ExecuteMethodCall(this,
   ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
   @string).ReturnValue));
}
```

The problem here is that this is from Linq to SQL and uses the `DataContext.ExecutMethodCall` function instead of the `DBContext` object used in EF 6 and there appears to be no equivalent method in `DBContext`

Any help on how to do this in EF6(Code first, no .edmx files) would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You've the following error

> "this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Because your query must be translated into SQL instructions therefore there is no available clause in SQL that can be mapped with `AlphanumComparatorFast`.

> Do I need to use a SQL function(or some such) or can this be done
>   using IQueryable?

Yes you need to translate the logic of your sorting written in C# composable with SQL by creating a SQL function on the server side and use it in your Linq to Entites query.

Comment: I figured as much. I now have a SQL Function to do the sorting, but have not found a good example of how to call it from C# using EF 6 Code First. Adding an update to the above question.